# Efficient Matrix subsetting with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to find an efficient way to subset a matrix with Rcpp for a **non-continuous** set of rows and columns:

```
m <- matrix(1:20000000, nrow=5000)

rows <- sample(1:5000, 100)
cols <- sample(1:4000, 100)
```

In R, the matrix can be directly subsetted using the `rows` and `cols` vectors:

```
matrix_subsetting <- function(m, rows, cols){
  return(m[rows, cols])
}

m[rows, cols]
# or
matrix_subsetting(m, rows, cols)
```

The fastest **Rcpp** way, I was able to find so far was:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("
```

```
  NumericMatrix cpp_matrix_subsetting(NumericMatrix m, NumericVector rows, NumericVector cols){
    
    int rl = rows.length();
    int cl = cols.length();
    NumericMatrix out(rl, cl);
    
    for (int i=0; i<cl; i++){
      NumericMatrix::Column org_c = m(_, cols[i]-1);
      NumericMatrix::Column new_c = out(_, i);
      for (int j=0; j<rl; j++){
        new_c[j] = org_c[rows[j]-1];
      }
    }
    return(out);
  }
```

```
")
```

But in comparison, the Rcpp version is significantly slower:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(matrix_subsetting(m, rows, cols), cpp_matrix_subsetting(m, rows, cols), times=500)
Unit: microseconds
                                 expr       min        lq       mean    median         uq        max neval
     matrix_subsetting(m, rows, cols)    23.269    90.127   107.8273   130.347   135.3285    605.235   500
 cpp_matrix_subsetting(m, rows, cols) 69191.784 75254.277 88484.9328 90477.448 95611.9090 178903.973   500
```

Any ideas, to get at least a comparable speed with Rcpp?

I already tried the `RcppArmadillo` `arma::mat::submat` function, but it is slower than my version.

---

**Solution:**

Implementation of the `cpp_matrix_subsetting` function with `IntegerMatrix` instead of `NumericMatrix`.

New benchmark:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(matrix_subsetting(m, rows, cols), cpp_matrix_subsetting(m, rows, cols), times=1e4)
Unit: microseconds
                                 expr    min     lq     mean median      uq      max neval
     matrix_subsetting(m, rows, cols) 41.110 60.261 66.88845 61.730 63.8900 14723.52 10000
 cpp_matrix_subsetting(m, rows, cols) 43.703 61.936 71.56733 63.362 65.8445 27314.11 10000
```

Comment: Have you tried on larger matrices? We're talking about milliseconds here.

Comment: I tried for larger matrices and the difference got even bigger. (I edited the question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you have a matrix `m` of type `integer` (not `double` as `NumericMatrix` is expecting) so this makes a copy of the entire matrix (which takes a lot of time).

For example, try with `m <- matrix(1:20000000 + 0, nrow=5000)` instead.

Comment: I rewrote the Rcpp function using an `IntegerMatrix` instead of `NumericMatrix` and it is now similarly fast as the R version.

Comment: You should make a function that detects the `SEXP` type and call 2 different functions.